# _header.php wont link to the .css

Tags: facebook

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>php-login-advanced</title>
<style type="text/css">
    <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    label {
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
        bottom: 1px;
    }
    input[type=text],
    input[type=password],
    input[type=submit],
    input[type=email] {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from login object)
if (isset($login)) {
if ($login->errors) {
    foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
if ($login->messages) {
    foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }
}
}
?>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
if ($registration->errors) {
    foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
if ($registration->messages) {
    foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }
}
}
?>
```

I am trying to get all my .php pages to match the .html pages. How ever I am having trouble getting the _header.php to work with the .css

do I need to do any thing to the _footer.php as well? thanks in advance. Just trying to get my whole web site to match.

Answer (score 0):

Illegal HTML/CSS. Anything you put inside a `<style>` block **MUST** be valid CSS. You've got a `<link>` element, which is NOT css.

Try

```
<LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
   ... blah blah blah...
</style>
```

Comment: could it be because there is "type=:text/css"> twice? once in the link and once below it.

Comment: Doens't matter how many/few times you have the type in there. Your CSS above is utterly broken because you've put an html link tag inside the style block. It'd be like doing `<script><a href="...">click me</a></script>`. html inside a script block is NOT javascript, and an outright syntax error, just like your link-in-css

Comment: so is there no way I can take the .css files and take the html to recreate it to work with the .php files? I downloaded a web template and wanted to take the look of the .html files and pull them over to work with the .php files. I thought linking the .php files by the _header.php would allow the .php files to use the basic web page layout of the .css file.

Comment: css has nothing to do with php. if the css isn't being loaded, then it's something about the html you're generating that's broken. css isn't where it should be, isn't readable by the webserver, etc... php has absolutely NO idea what html or css are - it's just a series of strings/characters.

Comment: thank you for your time and the information. I will figure out some thing else to make things work then.